# Set collection name dynamically with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to change the collection based on model data in mongoose. I am tapping into the pre save event:

```
mySchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    this.schema.set('collection', getCollectionName(this.dt));
    next();
});
```

But that seems to have no effect on the save destination. Those collections seemed to be set in the mongoose model already. Any ideas on where I might be able to set this after the model has been created?

Comment: I found a rather brute force way. In the function body: this.collection = new mongoose.Collection(getCollectionName(this.dt), mongoose.connection); ... Eeew.

Comment: Even if you get this to work, just be aware that any indexes you created in the schema (including the default unique index on the `_id` field) will not be applied to the other collections. The `ensureIndex` function is only called once for each defined index when the model is registered with mongoose.